# Unit-of-Work Design Pattern vs Transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, entity-framework-6, unit-of-work

With multiple SQL operations (such as a bank transfer or a purchase of a shopping cart full of products) the developer needs to bracket the operations within a Transaction and they either 1) all succeed (Commit) or 2) all fail (Rollback).

So, my question is what is UoW adding to this principle or how does it differ and do we need to implement the transaction support explicitly when using UOW in business problems like bank transfer or shopping cart when somebody will place a order?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should have a mechanism to handle each request as different session. If you are using .net you can refer to below link for how to handle session state. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Comment: You misunderstood mu question, I am talking about transaction support in unit of work design pattern.